# Primefaces como disparar o evento blur e atualizar os dados

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-3.5, primefaces-5.2

Estou precisando de uma ajuda com o Primefaces, eu preciso neste evento abaixo que já está meio encaminhado um exemplo que eu peguei do próprio Primefaces mais que depois vou adaptar para que eu quero, bom é uma grid editável já funcionando, daí você preenche a matricula e vai chamar um método, nesse método vou pesquisar as informações, e preencher mais dois campos da Datatable respectivamente, minha dúvida é, como eu pego essa linha que eu estou editando e disparo com o evento blur passando a matricula que vou querer pesquisar, e depois fazer ele atualizar essa mesma linha com esses dois novos campos preenchidos. Cai no meio do caminho em um projeto na empresa, e nunca trabalhei com Primefaces. Então resumidamente o que eu preciso é que o envento blur funcione que já consigue até funcionar já, mas não sei se é a melhor maneira e com isso vou ter que pegar essa matricula que digitei e conseguir pegar lá no Java pra poder fazer a pesquisa do Funcionário e pegar duas informações e preencher o Nome e o Turno no código abaixo.

```
<h:form id="form">
   <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

   <p:dataTable id="cars1" widgetVar="cars1" var="car" value="#{dtAddRowView.cars1}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
       <f:facet name="header">
           Funcionários
       </f:facet>

       <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{dtAddRowView.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />
       <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{dtAddRowView.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" />

       <p:column headerText="Matricula">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.id}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input">
               <p:inputText value="#{car.id}" style="width:100%" label="Matricula">
                    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{dtAddRowView.onRowSelect}" update="@form"/>
                </p:inputText>
               </f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Nome">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.year}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{car.year}" style="width:100%" label="Year" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Turno">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{car.brand}" style="width:100%" label="Year" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Transporte">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{car.soldState}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{car.soldState}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column style="width:32px">
           <p:rowEditor />
       </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>

    <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <p:commandButton value="Novo Registro" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" process="@this" update=":form:msgs"
                             actionListener="#{dtAddRowView.onAddNew()}" oncomplete="PF('cars1').addRow();"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Posta o código do dtAddRowView.onRowSelect por favor. Creio que seja por esse caminho: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989728/primefaces-inputtext-desnt-work-with-ajax-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que acabei fazendo ficou com o JSON vou chamando a cada requisição que vou alterando alguma coisa e envio no final como uma variável, Solução:

```
<h:form id="form">
   <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

   <p:dataTable id="dataTableAprovacaoFuncionario" widgetVar="listaAprovacaoFuncionario" var="aprovacaoFuncionario" value="#{aprovacaoFuncionarioHoraExtraView.listaAprovacaoFuncionario}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
       <f:facet name="header">
           Funcionários
       </f:facet>

       <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{aprovacaoFuncionarioHoraExtraView.onRowEdit}" update=":form:msgs, listaAprovacaoFuncionario"/>
       <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{aprovacaoFuncionarioHoraExtraView.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs, listaAprovacaoFuncionario"/>

       <p:column headerText="Matricula">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output">
                   <p:inputText value="#{aprovacaoFuncionario.matricula}" style="width:100%" label="Matricula">
                        <p:ajax event="change" onstart="selectedValueTipoRequisicao()"/>
                        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{aprovacaoFuncionarioHoraExtraView.selectRowAprovacaoFuncionario(aprovacaoFuncionario)}" update=":form:dataTableAprovacaoFuncionario, :form:msgs, listaAprovacaoFuncionario"/>
                    </p:inputText>
               </f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input">
                   <p:inputText id="matricula" value="#{aprovacaoFuncionario.matricula}" style="width:100%" label="Matricula">
                        <p:ajax event="change" onstart="selectedValueTipoRequisicao()"/>
                        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{aprovacaoFuncionarioHoraExtraView.selectRowAprovacaoFuncionario(aprovacaoFuncionario)}" update=":form:dataTableAprovacaoFuncionario, :form:msgs, listaAprovacaoFuncionario"/>
                    </p:inputText>
               </f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Nome">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{aprovacaoFuncionario.nome}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{aprovacaoFuncionario.nome}" style="width:100%" label="Nome" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Turno">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{aprovacaoFuncionario.turno}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{aprovacaoFuncionario.turno}" style="width:100%" label="Turno" disabled="true"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Transporte">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{aprovacaoFuncionario.transporte}">
                        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{aprovacaoFuncionarioHoraExtraView.selectRowAprovacaoFuncionario(aprovacaoFuncionario)}" update=":form:dataTableAprovacaoFuncionario, :form:msgs, listaAprovacaoFuncionario"/>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{aprovacaoFuncionario.transporte}" style="width:100%" label="Transporte">
                        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{aprovacaoFuncionarioHoraExtraView.selectRowAprovacaoFuncionario(aprovacaoFuncionario)}" update=":form:dataTableAprovacaoFuncionario, :form:msgs, listaAprovacaoFuncionario"/>
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column style="width:32px">
           <p:rowEditor />
       </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>

    <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <p:commandButton value="Novo Registro" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" process="@this" update=":form:msgs, listaAprovacaoFuncionario"
                             actionListener="#{aprovacaoFuncionarioHoraExtraView.onAddNew()}" oncomplete="PF('listaAprovacaoFuncionario').addRow();"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</h:form>

<p:inputText id="listaAprovacaoFuncionario" name="listaAprovacaoFuncionario" value="#{aprovacaoFuncionarioHoraExtraView.listaAprovacaoFuncionarioToJSON}" type="hidden">
        <p:ajax/>
</p:inputText>
```

No java sempre vou atualizando no final de cada método o JSON.

```
public String getListaAprovacaoFuncionarioToJSON () {

    String jsonListaAprovacaoFuncionario = new Gson().toJson(getListaAprovacaoFuncionario());

    return jsonListaAprovacaoFuncionario;
}
```

Na hora de enviar a solicitação pego a váriavel:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : '/populisII-web/rest/formulariodinamico/' + campoDoFormularioDinamico.idCampo + '/' + campoDoFormularioDinamico.idFormulario + '/porIdCampoEIdFormulario',
    dataType : "json",
    context : this
}).done(function(campoDoFormularioPreenchido){
    this.campoDoFormularioPreenchido = campoDoFormularioPreenchido;

    if (campoDoFormularioPreenchido != null) {

        $('#nomeFluxo').val(campoDoFormularioPreenchido.valorString);

        sessionStorage.removeItem("tipoRequisicao");

        var datasourceJSON = JSON.parse($('#listaAprovacaoFuncionario').val());

         $.each(datasourceJSON, function(index, objNumber) {

            if (index == 0) {
                if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(objNumber)) {
                    mostraInfos(["Informe pelo menos um Funcionário para a Aprovação de Hora Extra."]);
                    return;
                } else {
                    submeteFormulario();                                                    
                }
            }
         });
    }
})
```